# How to stop Xamarin from initializing every view in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, custom-controls

I have two custom views in a page, only one of them should be visible at a time.
I want the view to be initialized only when it becomes visible*. But what happens is that Xamarin initializes EVERY view in the page, I tried several ways, trying to tell Xamarin: "don't initialize it now", this is one of them:

```
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding ViewType,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <views:View1/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding ViewType,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <views:View2/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ContentView.Triggers>
</ContentView>
```

What I expected when I first tried this code is: when the `ViewType` changes to `0`, the `Content` property gets a fresh `new View1()`, and the same with `View2`, but both are initialized when the page loads at first time only.

To illustrate why I need this, I have a page that shows either a map or a `CollectionView`, due to the binding limitations in the map control, I do all the work when the control is initialized in the code-behind, so whenever the view holding the map becomes visible (meaning data might have changed) I need to re-initialize the control to update the map.

What I want to achieve, according to the above example, is when the custom view become visible, I want it to be initialized, whether when the page loads or when the data binding changes.

*by *visibility* I mean its presence on the display, not strictly the `IsVisible` property.

Comment: if you want more control, then build it in C#, not XAML

Comment: I hoped to stay away from this option at least now, the project is old and complex to make this change

Comment: That is how `DataTriggers` work they keep all options ready and replace as soon as the Trigger is been invoked!

Comment: @FreakyAli I think every view in XAML pages get initialized when the page loads, no matter how it's embedded

Comment: Well isn't that what we usually want? Your case is an exception obviously

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear if what you are trying to achieve is the best suitable way but anyway, to have what you what you need to do the following:

1 For this case forget triggers and create a custom control (if you are unsure how then i could update this answer) that would react to your ViewModel and set content to the appropriate view from code-behind like

```
this.Content = new View1();
```

2 put this custom control instead of what you have actually, for example:

```
<controls:MyUberControl Mode="{Binding ViewType}">
```

Comment: What is this? can you clarify please.. what is the use of the custom control?

Comment: Do you mean in the `propertyChanged` of the `Mode` I change the `Content` property?

Comment: Yes you got it totally right. Do you still need more help?